# Can I use 3D coordinates as a CNN input?

Tags: tensorflow, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am fairly new to neural networks and I am planning to train a network using 3D data (3D face scans in .obj). I don't want to use a 3D CNN but rather transform my data to a image-like structure and train a 2D CNN. With my idea that would require placing my 3D points on a 2D grid so that the input would be just like with images but with XYZ coordinates instead of RGB.
Is it a sensible idea that could work with CNN? If so, what is the best way to build that 2D projection?

Comment: I do not know what is your final target but this guys did a great job in a similar problem recently: http://blog.kaggle.com/2017/06/29/2017-data-science-bowl-predicting-lung-cancer-2nd-place-solution-write-up-daniel-hammack-and-julian-de-wit/

Comment: First I want to try some basic age/gender classification using some crops of the mesh(like nose for example). Thank you for the link, it's a very interesting reading and I might reconsider my initial idea of doing the 2D projection. Though I am still curious whether my approach might work to and if so then how to do it correctly.

Comment: For doing that, a simple 2D image would be enough. So I think that you would like to transform your 3D image in a frontal image of the person? Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, but doing that I would lose a lot of information wouldn't I? I thought that points that are not visible from frontal view could be also placed in the 2D grid and my input would be in form Xyz for each "pixel"

Comment: Just use a 3D CNN?..

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but doing that I would lose a lot of information wouldn't I? I thought that points that are not visible from frontal view could be also placed in the 2D grid and my input would be in form Xyz for each "pixel"

Comment: Yes, you would lose a lot of information. But you would simplify the problem a lot too and you want to figure out the age of a person, so you should keep things simple for the NN regression.
If I were you I would proceed stepwise, try with something simple and keep adding complexity to it (only if necessary).

Comment: So if I did a CNN with frontal images, my input would be images with 1 channel, no 3D coordinates?

Comment: No, take the 3 channels (RGB) if you can, you need to find a transformation to convert your image to 2D with 3 channels. I think you need get more insights about how do CNN work, take a look at this tutorial I always recommend it for people that know Neural Nets and want to start with Conv. ones https://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/

Answer (score 1):

How about using a frontal RGB image interleaved with an additional frontal depth texture, found by rendering the depth from the front (or from original scanner data, if it was a frontal scan) ? That would then be a job for a 2D CNN with four channels, I think.